# Tkinterhtml fails to run on raspbian. Python 3.7

Tags: raspbian, python-3, tkinter

Tkinterhtml fails to run on Raspbian. Python 3.7

```
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't load file "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tkinterhtml/tkhtml/Linux/32-bit/Tkhtml/libTkhtml3.0.so": 
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tkinterhtml/tkhtml/Linux/32-bit/Tkhtml/libTkhtml3.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

above is the error message. The "libTkhtml3.0.so" appears to only be for x86 platforms. Any ideas?

Comment: Which OS do you have? Python 3.7 is not preinstalled on the current Raspbian Stretch images. How did you install tkinterhtml?

Comment: Latest Raspbian.

Comment: Please answer other question, and also how did you install Python 3.7?

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. I think it would be helpful to address Dirk's suggestion and edit those facts into the question/answer where appropriate. It'll be helpful to future readers to also know what *not* to do... Also note that you may accept your own answer - check the tick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it:

```
sudo apt-get install tk-html3
```